# Self-adjoint, strictly singular operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be infinite-dimensional Banach spaces. Recall that an operator $T: X\rightarrow Y$ is strictly singular if it is not an isomorphic embedding when restricted to any infinite-dimensional closed subspace of $X$. An operator $T: X\rightarrow Y$ is completely continuous if it maps weakly convergent sequences to norm convergent sequences.

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and $T: H\rightarrow H$ be a self-adjoint operator. My question is:

Q: If $T$ is strictly singular, is $T$ necessarily completely continuous?

Comment: Yes, because the spectral projection on $\{ |z|>r\}$ has to be finite dimensional for arbitrary $r>0$, so $T$ is compact (I'm assuming that $T$ is bounded, which seems to make sense, given the question).

Comment: @ChristianRemling, Thanks, Christian. Because my research area is Banach space theory  not operator theory, I do not understand the spectral projection. Could you give a self-contained and detailed proof?

Comment: You will find the spectral theorem in any basic functional analysis text.

Comment: It is elementary that every strictly singular operator on a Hilbert space is compact.  This is also true for $\ell_p$, $1\le p < \infty$ and $c_0$.  No spectral theory is needed; just standard gliding hump arguments that are contained in e.g. Albiac-Kalton and Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri.

Comment: @BillJohnson, Standard gliding hump arguments can be used for $l_{p}$ and $c_{0}$ because  $l_{p}$ and $c_{0}$ have the unit vector basis. But there is no orthogonal basis in general Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @BillJohnson,  I know the proof.

Comment: @dongyangChen If $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq\mathcal{H}$ is bounded and $T\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is strictly singular then to prove $T$ is also compact we want to find a convergent subsequence of $(Tx_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. If we put $X=[x_n]_{n=1}^\infty$ and $Y=[Tx_n]_{n=1}^\infty$ the operator $T|_X:X\to Y$ is now a strictly singular operator. Assume both $X$ and $Y$ are infinite-dimensional, else we are done already. As they are infinite-dimensional separable closed subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$, they are isomorphic to $\ell_2$. So the nonseparable case always reduces to the separable.